# Django1.8 and Mongoengine NameError: name 'IntegerField' is not defined

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django 1.8 and my project needs to connect to one instances of MongoDB while another with sql.But i am getting this error-

command prompt-

```
python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/admin_app/models.py", line 212, in <module>
    class location(Document):
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/admin_app/models.py", line 213, in location
    user_id = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NameError: name 'IntegerField' is not defined
```

my setting.py file-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    },

}

from mongoengine import connect
connect(
db='pom',
username='admin',
password='root',
host='mongodb://admin:root@localhost'
)
```

so First i decided to complete all work related to mongodb then i will move on to sql.This is the code for model of mongodb database
my model.py file -

```
class location(Document):
        user_id = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        name = CharField(max_length=100)
        loc_lon = FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        timestamp = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        activity = StringField()
        lot_lat = FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        batter_status = StringField()
        address = StringField()
        date_created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and plz can someone refer any MongoEngine and Django1.8 tutorial ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timestamp = IntField(blank=True, null=True)
```

but its better to use

```
timestamp = DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

as its a timestamp

Comment: Thnx for this. I edit it but i am still stuck with this error :(

Comment: still same error -  NameError: name 'IntegerField' is not defined

Comment: its IntField not IntegerField, check the ans

Comment: ohk sry my bad .but now i am getting another error - NameError: name 'CharField' is not defined

Comment: there is no CharField use StringField()

Answer (score 0):

`IntergerField` is not valid, use `IntField` instead.

```
user_id = IntField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Ref: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.IntField